# How to change the grid snapping values for every axis individual?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I would like to change the grid values per axis, to get individual snapping values direction constrained.

**Current situation for a grid in blender:**

Scale for x,y,z = 1 (Objects moves using value of 1 in every direction, when snapping is on.)

**I would like to set the follwing values f.e.:**

Scale for x,y,z = 1, 1, 0.5

So the object would move per 1 unit to x and y, and 0.5 units upwards (z-axis).

Is this possible?

At the end I would like to set the grid individually for every axis.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.